# How to filter files (with known type) from os.walk?

Tags: python

I have list from `os.walk`. But I want to exclude some directories and files. I know how to do it with directories:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/My_files/test'):
    if "Update" in dirs:
        dirs.remove("Update")
```

But how can I do it with files, which type I know. because this doesn't work:

```
if "*.dat" in files:
    files.remove("*.dat")
```

Answer (score 59):

```
files = [ fi for fi in files if not fi.endswith(".dat") ]
```

Answer (score 32):

Exclude multiple extensions.

```
files = [ file for file in files if not file.endswith( ('.dat','.tar') ) ]
```

Answer (score 10):

And in one more way, because I just wrote this, and then stumbled upon this question:

`files = filter(lambda file: not file.endswith('.txt'), files)`

Mote that in python3 filter returns a generator, not a list, and the list comprehension is "preferred".

Answer (score 5):

A concise way of writing it, if you do this a lot:

```
def exclude_ext(ext):
    def compare(fn): return os.path.splitext(fn)[1] != ext
    return compare

files = filter(exclude_ext(".dat"), files)
```

Of course, exclude_ext goes in your appropriate utility package.

Answer (score 4):

Should be exactly what you need:

```
if thisFile.endswith(".txt"):
```

Comment: not too mention that it's not clear what are you going to do on the next line.

Answer (score 3):

```
files = [file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1] != '.dat']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import os

skippingWalk = lambda targetDirectory, excludedExtentions: (
    (root, dirs, [F for F in files if os.path.splitext(F)[1] not in excludedExtentions]) 
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(targetDirectory)
)

for line in skippingWalk("C:/My_files/test", [".dat"]):
    print line
```

This is a generator expression generating lambda function. You pass it a path and some extensions, and it invokes os.walk with the path, filters out the files with extensions in the list of unwanted extensions using a list comprehension, and returns the result.

(edit: removed the `.upper()` statement because there might be an actual difference between extensions of different case - if you want this to be case insensitive, add `.upper()` after `os.path.splitext(F)[1]` and pass extensions in in capital letters.)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to filter files with a known type with os.walk() is to tell the path and get all the files filtered by the extension with an if statement.

```
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

    if files.endswith('.type'):

       #Here you will go through all the files with the particular extension '.type'
       .....
       .....
```

Comment: Be careful, os.walk returns a generator yielding root, dirs and files, `files` being a *list* of files. I think the answers with list comprehension and filter make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use the functions from [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) module:

```
def MatchesExtensions(name,extensions=["*.dat", "*.txt", "*.whatever"]):
  for pattern in extensions:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(pattern):
      return True
  return False
```

This way you avoid all the hassle with upper/lower case extension. This means you don't need to convert to lower/upper when having to match *.JPEG, *.jpeg, *.JPeg, *.Jpeg

Answer (score 2):

here is how to find all files in a directory ending with a specific extension

```
 import glob, os
 path=os.path.expanduser('C:\\Users\\A')
 for filename in [item for item in os.listdir(path) if item.endswith(".ipynb")  ]:
       print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are working. Just wanted to add for anyone else whos files by any chance are coming from heterogeneous sources, e.g. downloading images in archives from the Internet. In this case, because Unix-like systems are case sensitive you may end up having extension like '.PNG' and '.png'. These will be treated by  as different strings by `endswith` method, i.e. `'.PNG'.endswith('png')` will return `False`. In order to avoid this problem, use `lower()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In these two ways I can select the files by the file type:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

source_path = './data'

excelfiles = [f for f in listdir(source_path) if f.endswith(('.xlsx')) and isfile(join(source_path, f))]


from os import walk

excelfiles2 = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(source_path):
    excelfiles2.extend(filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith('.xlsx'))
    break
```