# In python, how do I exclude files from a loop if they begin with a specific set of letters?

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a Python script that goes through a directory and gathers certain files, but there are a number of files I want excluded that all start the same.

Example code:

```
for name in files:
   if name != "doc1.html" and name != "doc2.html" and name != "doc3.html":
      print name
```

Let's say there are 100 hundred HTML files in the directory all beginning with `'doc'`. What would be the easiest way to exclude them?

Sorry I'm new to Python, I know this is probably basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes it just eludes me - how and why such questions get 4 upvotes. Apart from being a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176441/how-to-filter-files-with-known-type-from-os-walk and some other questions, it is absolutely trivial and shows a basic lack of awareness of what tools the language provides

Comment: @Eli: Are you saying we should ignore the trivial and basic questions? Just because something is trivial and basic to you doesn't mean it isn't complex and new to someone else.

Comment: Thank You Daniel,  basically I needed a quick fix, and I came to the right place because I had the solution in less then a minute.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think he's saying not to ask simple questions, just that people shouldn't vote them up. Unfortunately, complex questions will probably appeal to a narrower audience and get fewer votes. Oh, so there's your answer Eli.

Comment: I'm with @Eli, upvote means there is something noteworthy or interesting about the question.  This is elementary.

Comment: @Daniel: No, of course not. You will never catch me noobie-bashing. But what is the point of 4 upvotes for a trivial, duplicate question?

Comment: @Ruth: I have absolutely nothing against your asking this question. I'm glad you got help - this is what SO is for. I'm having qualms with the voting here that skews reality sometimes

Comment: @telliott99, upvote means (and I quote directly from the mouseover text) "This question is useful and clear".  That includes neither "noteworthy" nor "interesting".  I'm quite sure many people upvote merely because the question is concise and clear.

Comment: Not to split hairs or anything :), but I would argue that useful implies either "noteworthy" or "interesting."

Comment: @telliott99, subjective.  I think both "noteworthy" and "interesting" require a degree of novelty, while "useful" certainly does not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
if not name.startswith('doc'):
     print name
```

If you have more prefixes to exclude you can even do this:

```
if not name.startswith(('prefix', 'another', 'yetanother')):
     print name
```

[startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) can accept a tuple of prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

If you find functional programming matches your style better, Python makes it simple to filter lists with the filter() function:

```
>>> files = ["doc1.html", "doc2.html", "doc3.html", "index.html", "image.jpeg"]
>>> filter_function = lambda name: not name.startswith("doc")
>>> filter(filter_function, files)
['index.html', 'image.jpeg']
```

Also take a look at apply(), map(), reduce(), and zip().

Comment: But note that `apply()` has been deprecated since 2.3: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply

Answer (score 5):

```
for name in files:
    if not name.startswith("doc"):
        print name
```

Comment: What I'm lookin for would be the opposite of startswith, if there was a method called doesnotstartwith(), I'd be sorted :)

Comment: sorry, dunno how I missed that

Answer (score 4):

looks like this problem might be a better fit for list stuff 
so like Troy said (Although I prefer putting the function directly into the filter)

```
filter(lambda filename: not filename.startswith("doc"),files)
```

or

```
[filename for filename in files if not filename.startswith("doc")]
```

Comment: i would say that this is the pythonic way to go :p

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.chdir("/home")
for file in os.listdir("."):
   if os.path.isfile(file) and not file.startswith("doc"):
      print file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
cleaned_list = [filename for filename in files if not filename.startswith('doc')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my 2 cents:
A bit of list comprehension.It's always better for effeciency.

```
file_list = [file for file in directory if not file.startswith(("name1", "name2", "name3"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in files:
    if name[0:3] == "doc":
         continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of them start the same (i.e. with "doc") you could use python's string's startswith() method.

```
for name in files:
    if not name.startswith("doc"):
       print name
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say if there are good files starting with 'doc' and ending with '.html' you will have to declare a `set` of bad filenames and process only files not in that set.

```
bad_files = set(["doc1.html", "doc2.html", "doc3.html"])

for file in files:
  if file not in bad_files:
    print file
```

If you need to dynamically change the list of filenames use a `list`.

Comment: At least use a set instead of a list. set lookup is O(1), list lookup is O(N).

Comment: @Nadia Alramli changed to example like you suggested

Comment: You changed it to a tuple, not a set. It should be: bad_files = set(["doc1.html", "doc2.html", "doc3.html"])

Answer (score 0):

An alternate take to a functional solution to this issue, with the advantage of using recent additions to the standard library (using the same example filenames as Troy J. Farrell in another answer) :

```
>>> import operator, itertools
>>> filter_fun= operator.methodcaller("startswith", "doc")
>>> files = ["doc1.html", "doc2.html", "doc3.html", "index.html", "image.jpeg"]
>>> list(itertools.ifilterfalse(filter_fun, files))
['index.html', 'image.jpeg']
```

`operator.methodcaller` called with `methodname, [optional arguments]` returns a function that, when called with an object `obj` as its argument, returns the result of `obj.methodname(optional_arguments)`.
`itertools.ifilterfalse`, unlike `filter`, returns an iterator instead of a list and the filter decision is negated.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the files that you want to exclude while iterating over all the files present in the folder.
Below code would skip all the html files that start with 'doc'

```
import glob
import re
for file in glob.glob('*.html'):
    if re.match('doc.*\.html',file):
        continue
    else:
        #do your stuff here
        print(file)
```