# Rename Files without Extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I got a Directory `Dir` and in `Dir` there are three subdirectories with five Files each:

1. Dir/A/ one,two,three,four,five.txt
2. Dir/B/ one,two,three,four,five.txt
3. Dir/C/ one,two,three,four,five.txt

As you can see there are four Files without extension and one with the `.txt`extension

How do I rename all Files without extension in a recursive manner?

Currently I'm trying this, which works for a single Directory, but how could I catch all Files if I put this Script into `Dir`?

```
import os, sys

for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
    base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext == "":
        os.rename(filename, base_file + ".png")
```

Comment: Have a look at os.walk() and maybe this SO-question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176441/how-to-filter-files-with-known-type-from-os-walk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `os.walk` if you want to perform recursive traversal.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
    for file in files:
        base_path, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, file))

        if not ext:
            os.rename(base_path, base_path + ".png")
```

---

`os.walk` will segregate your files into normal files and directories, so `os.path.isdir` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

my_dir = os.getcwd()
for root, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(my_dir):
    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.count('.'): continue  # don't process a file with an extension
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, fname), os.path.join(root, "{}.png".format(fname)))
```